# How to replace matplotlib legend and keep same location?

Tags: python, matplotlib, location, legend

I'd like to replace a matplotlib legend with a new one, but keep the same (possibly arbitrary) location of the legend being replaced.

Why won't the following code work?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))
ax = plt.gca()

leg = plt.legend(['a'], loc='lower left')
bb = leg.get_bbox_to_anchor().inverse_transformed(ax.transAxes)

plt.legend(['b'], bbox_to_anchor=bb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question why the code in the question wouldn't work:
The legend's position is determined only at runtime when the figure is drawn. Additionally the bbox_to_anchor is not set, so it will be the complete axes (`(0,0,1,1)`).

What you can do is first draw the canvas and then obtain the window extent

```
ax.figure.canvas.draw()
bb = leg.get_window_extent().inverse_transformed(ax.transAxes)
```

This however will not give you the correct position (only close to it).

Now a possible solution might be not to replace the legend, but instead only update it's content:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))
ax = plt.gca()

leg = plt.legend(['a'], loc='lower left')

leg.texts[0].set_text("b")

plt.show()
```

Otherwise, if updating is not an option, you would need the bbox_to_anchor and the loc parameter from the old legend:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))
ax = plt.gca()

leg = plt.legend(['a'], loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5,0.5))

bb = leg.get_bbox_to_anchor().inverse_transformed(ax.transAxes)
plt.legend(['b'], bbox_to_anchor=bb, loc=leg._loc_real) 

plt.show()
```

This may still fail in cases, where mode has been set to "expand". It is also only accurate when the same fancybox paramters are used to create the new legend.

Comment: It would be nice to just update the contents. However, I don't think it's possible to update all the properties that I need: fontsize, numpoints, scatterpoints, labelspacing, handletextpad, borderaxespad, borderpad, handlelength, and fancybox. I think several of these can only be accessed through the legend command at creation.

Comment: Is there a way to determine how/where the legend is anchored? For example, the lower left corner of the legend is anchored to the lower left corner of the axes. If so, then I could just set the `loc='lower left'`...

Comment: I updated the answer. Maybe this is closer on what you need.

Comment: `_loc_real` is just what I needed! Do you know what the difference is between `_loc_real` and `_loc`?

Comment: The one is more real than the other. ;-) No, honestly, I have no clue at the moment.

Comment: Looking at the `legend.py` matplotlib file I found that `_loc` is a property of the `Legend` class with `_set_loc` and `_get_loc` setter and getter, respectively. `_loc_real` is the attribute set by `_set_loc` and returned by `_get_loc`, so `_loc` is the "more public" interface to `_loc_real`. While neither are "public" in the conventional sense, I suppose it is more appropriate to access `_loc` and not `_loc_real`.

Answer (score 0):

unless I'm misunderstanding, just do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))
ax = plt.gca()

location = 'lower left'

while 1:

    plt.legend(['a'], loc=location)
    plt.pause(1)
    plt.legend(['b'], loc=location)
    plt.pause(1)
```

Comment: I should have clarified that the original legend location is not known, in addition to possibly being arbitrary. This can happen if, for instance, the figure is loaded from a pickle file.